# No "Distribution" setting in latest Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode3.2

For some reason, a choice for "Distribution" configuration is not showing up for building an app in the latest Xcode 3.2.2 with iPhone SDK 3.2 when I'm trying to build an app for the iPad

Any one else seeing this?  I can set it to "Debug" or "Release" but there isn't even an option for Distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double Click on the .xcodeproj icon in the left pane, I believe called Groups & Files. Then, In the Configuration Tab, duplicate the "Release" and rename it "Distribution".

Answer (score 3):

You add it yourself.  Duplicate the `Release` config.